# Add existing person to event in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm having difficulties understanding how I can add an existing object (of type person) to another table (event) in Ruby-on-Rails. I created a many-to-many-relationship between the table person and table event, but now I don't know how to add an existing person to an existing event. These are my models:

Person:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
has_many :messages
has_and_belongs_to_many :event

validates :name, presence: true
validates :email, presence: true
validates :birth, presence: true
end
```

Event:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
has_many :messages
has_and_belongs_to_many :people

validates :title, presence: true
validates :description, presence: true
validates :minimum_age, presence: true
validates :maximum_age, presence: true
validates_numericality_of :maximum_age, :greater_than => :minimum_age
validates :start, presence: true
validates :end, presence: true
end
```

Now, I made this form in the event's view using the official rails tutorial:

```
<%= form_for([@event, @event.people.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :email %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<%end%>
```

Obviously the form_for-parameters are wrong, but I really don't know what they should be? I just want the user to fill in his e-mail address (that corresponds to an existing person) and register the user as an attendant for this event. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is a bit broad but I'll try to help you in general things.

To add `person` to `event` you may want:

1. Set up your new `person` view with form. Rails default generated view will do.
2. Use in your form `select_tag` helper with list of all present `events` and their ID's.
3. With that when you create new `person` you need to choose `event` from select box. When you select it and submit the form, Rails stores ID of chosen event to `event_id` attribute of `person` object and put it in the DB.
4. Make sure you've added to strong parameters all attributes needed.

My tips are broad and they require some amount fo googling from you. But without more details of your current setup it's all I can.